# Can point mass have vibrational motion?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Can a point mass have vibrational motion. I have read that reason for point mass is to ensure that we can idealize translational motion and don't have to worry about rotational and vibrational motion. Is that correct?

Comment: You mean internal degrees of freedom? The whole point of the point mass approximation is to not having to worry about rotational and vibrational degrees of freedom of real objects. If you want to analyze those, you need, at least, two coupled masses or, in general, an extended mass distribution.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by vibrational motion. A point mass indeed does not have *internal* vibrational degrees of freedom, it can just have translational motion, as you pointed out.

However, if you attach this point mass to a spring you create a harmonic oscillator. It has a translational motion, but this oscillating motion can describe *vibrations* such as vibrations of atoms around their equilibrium state in a solid.